# How to embed my recent video shared on YouTube?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

Tried to read the [official](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/youtube/overview.html) guide about embedding video on my website, but I don't find the part which teach how to embed the last video loaded on my youtube zone.

Is it possible (using JS API)?

**EDIT** Callback for check a video and do some things

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/MyNickname/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showMyVideos(data) {
            alert("Hello");
        }
    </script>         
</head>
```

this should show my alert, but nothing happens. Why=

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following URL to get the list of uploaded video by particular user in JSON format.

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/GoogleDevelopers/uploads?alt=json
```

Note : alt=json and to replace GoogleDevelopers with your user.

You could use [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to get the data from the URL then just get the first feed (the latest one)

Comment: But this is only using the Data API...! Can't I do it with this http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html ?

Comment: Uhm...I think I'll use these Data API with the .NET library (in fact in future I'll use comments+votes for the video that I embed on my website)

Comment: You use the URL to get the data. They would go to fetch the same data at the end. You only need to use the JS API to put the video up once you have the video ID. See this link http://gdata.ops.demo.googlepages.com/yt_json_codelab.html and read the section "Making it more attractive"

Comment: Uhm...for what I've see with Javascript I cannot put a Comments field (with relative auth for all users who visit the website), or am I wrong?

Comment: Comments link are available as part the request. Something like http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/videos/23KjpxcXhPY/comments?alt=json. You would need call via AJAX to parse this again and put it in HTML via appropriate JS. Alternatively, you could do everything on the backend. Eventually, it is your decision to build the page via JS or handle it in the backend. The source would be the same for both.

Comment: Yeah, but with this I think I can retrieve only data. If I want to make the box as "Write a comment" Youtube's widget, can I with Javascript?

Comment: P.S. using `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/users/MyNickname/uploads?alt=json-in-script&format=5&callback=showMyVideos` the callback `showMyVideos` is not called... why?

Comment: Looks like you could by making AJAX call to their Comments API, but it is painful as I only see the POST using XML. You might want to wrap that functionality on your server side and call the AJAX to your server web service instead going directly via YouTube API (unless you found that their API support POST via JSON as well).

Comment: Reverse the scripts. The function is undefined by the time you call the YouTube. Put showMyVideos before the YouTube script tag

Comment: I was tired! Yes it works :) Thanks man... I'll avoid comments/rate video (it is too extreme with Javascript API).

Comment: Ok! Now I have the list of my content of youtube profile. How can I get video (not IMG) and the last one?

Comment: Good to hear we are making progress :) It would be good if we possibly get this on another question, put what you have and start from there. I'll try to put up the answer there

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use [this section of the YT Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#User_Uploaded_Videos).  The order of returned videos is most recently uploaded first, so you can just grab the first off the returned list.

For example:

[https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/SocialGo/uploads?alt=json&fields=entry/id,entry/published](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/SocialGo/uploads?alt=json&fields=entry/id,entry/published)

Comment: Yeah...this is about Data API (which I never work on it). Is it impossible to do it with standard Embedded Player and JS callback?

Comment: Nope. But it looks like you're on the right track with the other answer.